# jquery date picker unable to remove the id and set the date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

In my project, i have a table tr, which has the date picker, on click i am clone the date picker,

And i understand, when i use the same id, will not work for the date picker, so i decide to remove the 'id' but i can't.

How to duplicate the existing 'tr' with date picker to work..

the code I used :

```
$("table").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find("tr:last").clone(false).removeClass('hasDatepicker').attr('id',"").appendTo($(this)).datepicker();
});


$("input").datepicker();
```

here is the [here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ha6xB/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has couple of problems..

Firstly `input` element can have the datepicker and not the row. In your code you were trying to add datepicker to the `tr` element.

Then after cloning and appending the row, you need to search for the input in the row and then add the `datepicker` to it

```
$("table").on("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find("tr:last").clone(false).find('input').removeClass('hasDatepicker')
            .attr('id', "").end().appendTo('table')
    $this.find("tr:last").find('input').datepicker();
});
$("input").datepicker();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Ha6xB/1/)**